# A cookie disappears after a few seconds and a problem with SameSite is mentioned

Tags: cookies, setcookie, samesite

A template of the cookie set follows (I altered the "Domain" part for privacy).

```
msgshowed=yes; expires=Fri, 24 Feb 2023 16:26:36 GMT; path=/; Domain=www.domain.org; SameSite=Strict
```

This cookie should let avoid to display a modal message every time the page is loaded

For a few seconds I see it is alive and does its job: it is found and the modal message is not showed upon page reloading. If I stop reloading, though, a message appears in the same console telling me about a not proper "SameSite" attribute value and I cannot see the cookie anymore in the "storage" tab.

*Cookie “msgshowed” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite*

Any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Andrea

**UPDATE**

Mysteriously the cookie stopped disappearing after I altered the "path" value (the page was not the home page) and also omitting that attribute did help. This is driving me nuts.

Besides, **the mentioned problem with SameSite is still there** and is shown repeatedly in the console.
Furthemore now another message repeatedly arises from jquery.cookie.min.js.

***Cookie “msgshowed” has been rejected for invalid domain.***

I tried different values for *Domain*, I also tried to omit that parameter. I also tried to reduce the cookie string to the bare minimum, omitting *Domain*, *path* and *SameSite*. No way, those two messages keep being showed in the console.

Comment: Does the cookie disappear because of its expiry date?

Comment: The date was not the reason. Apparently the disappearance stopped after I altered the value of the "path" parameter. It was set to "/". I set it to explicitly to the current page and I also tried to omit the parameter. The current page is after all the default. This does not make sense to me at all.